# Connecting ssh from ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

I want to connect to ssh from Ubuntu terminal but I don't know how. I have searched it on google but I don't understand. I have an IP address, username and password. If someone can explain to me how it's done, please do. I have tried:

```
ssh root@ipadress
```

(instead of 'ipadress' from this command, of course it's the real IP address)

then it requests the password, I write it, but it keep asking for it like this:

```
Enter passphrase for key '.../...':
Enter passphrase for key '.../...':
```

The connection dates are correct because from windows, it works to connect.

I have tried this:

```
 ssh user@localhost
 ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Passphrase is a different thing than password. Apart from that, what does 'alias ssh' say?

Comment: Your private key is password-protected. You can regenerate it using `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: Secure Shell, but I am new to this. If you can give me an example how to connect it will be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Please give us some more information. What OS is your local machine running? Are both local and remote machines running Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The computer you are trying to connect to, should have `openssh-server` running.

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server` will do the job for Ubuntu.

After that you can connect in that fashion:

`ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and the server will ask for your credentials.

Where x* is your ip and user is the user you want to connect as at your server, who should have an user account in the server.

Answer (score 0):

The key name should be something like ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Try to rename it ( `mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa.back` ) and try again.

This way, the ssh command will not use your key to authenticate, but password instead.

Answer (score 0):

If find out what was the problem. I needed to do this thing:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

and after that write my personal passphrase and just after that write the password for the connection.